# How do I store an input as a global variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am an absolute newbie when it comes to python and am learning by doing via my own text adventure game.

I have some code that enables the user to input their name:

```
# player name
def playerName():
    name = ""
    name = input("Before we begin, what is your name, warrior? ") 
    print("\n")
    print("Welcome {}, now be on your way!".format(name))
    print("\n")
```

This works as it is supposed to in the game. The player inputs their name and the game continues. However, I would like to be able to print the player's input later on in a different function and keep running the error message that name is undefined..  So I am trying to store this input as a global variable. I think that is the correct method, yes?

I have read up about storing functions as a global variable but these are always already specified by the programmer, i.e. `name = sarah`.

How do I store the input so that I can print it later on? I thought `print("string" + name)` would have been enough later on. But I have obviously misunderstood something.

Comment: Globals, especially modifiable globals, break modularity, so if you're not careful the program soon  becomes one big tangled mess that's difficult to analyze. So try to keep their use to a minimum. Group related items together in collections like lists and dicts, or custom classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the variable as global and access it whenever and whereever you want. For example:

```
# player name

name = ""

def playerName():
    global name
    name = input("Before we begin, what is your name, warrior? ")
    print("\n")
    print("Welcome {}, now be on your way!".format(name))
    print("\n")

def printname():
    print(name)

playerName()
printname()
```

Output:

```
Before we begin, what is your name, warrior? hari


Welcome hari, now be on your way!


hari
```

Explanation:

Declare a variable `name` at first of the file and access it using `global` keyword. So the value stored in that variable is accessed by multiple functions as mentioned in the code

Comment: @Cl4rify: This is tested in my local PC and added. Please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your file, create the variable:

```
name = None

# other functions....

def function_you_want_to_use_name_in():
    global name
    print(name)

def main():
    global name
    name = input("Before we begin, what is your name, warrior? ") 
    print("\n")
    print("Welcome {}, now be on your way!\n".format(name))
```

You don't have to include `global name` in `function_you_want_to_use_name_in` if you're just printing the value; theres no other variable named `name` in the function, so python uses the global value. I usually include it anyways, as it makes it clearer whats happening.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment - helped a lot :)